# html5 validation error output

Tags: html, validation, markup

I've tried to validate my html5 document although I am getting some invalid markup errors.

My code is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
    <html lang="en">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>index</title>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/base.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

The errors are:

```
    Line 7, Column 16: application/xhtml+xml is not an appropriate Content-Type for a document whose root element is not in a namespace. **<html lang="en">**

    Line 7, Column 16: Unnamespaced element html not allowed in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.) **<html lang="en">**

    Line 16, Column 3: required character (found h) (expected l) **</head>**
```

Some expert advise would be highly appreciated.

Thank you,
Patrick

Comment: Remove `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and it should validate.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 is HTML not XHTML (XML), so the `<?xml ... ?>` is causing validation problems (as Aaron already said)

Answer (score 1):

Just add the XHTML namespace to the html element, like this : `<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`.
Your code still won't be valid, because you forgot to add the additional backslashes to the void elements (meta and link).